# How to catch an Alt + Up arrow event in NSTextView

Tags: swift, nstextview

I’m using an NSTextView in my swift OS X application. When the user presses ctrl + up arrow then something happens.

I’m doing this by overriding the NSTextView onKeyDown function.

My code looks like this.

```
class MyTextView: NSTextView {
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        //NSLog(“event.keyCode=\(event.keyCode),modifierFlags=\(event.modifierFlags)”)
        // Do something on Alt + Up
        if event.keyCode == 126 && event.modifierFlags.rawValue == 11010336 {
        // Do something…
        }
}
```

This works, but when the caps lock key is on, it stopes working.
I guess its because event.modifierFlags.rawValue no longer equals 1010336.

My question is - Is there a more elegant way to catch the Alt + Up arrow even then to specify both event.modifierFlags.rawValue == 11010336 and the event value for when the caps lock is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a more elegant way:

```
if event.keyCode == 126 && event.modifierFlags.contains(.control) {
```

or for the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key

```
if event.keyCode == 126 && event.modifierFlags.contains(.option) {
```

Comment: Works great for Ctrl + Up. Would there be a similar solution for Alt + Up?

Answer (score 1):

And another way: override `moveToBeginningOfParagraph:`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Willeke's answer, I think the correct way to do this is to link up an NSTextViewDelegate for the text view, then handle the following.

```
func textView(_ textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool
{
  if commandSelector == #selector(textView.moveToBeginningOfParagraph(_:)) 
  {
    // Do something and tell the view you have handled it
    return true
  }

  return false // You haven't handled anything else
}
```